# Remove curly brackets via "Find and replace" in VSCode

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, replace, import

I need to remove brackets around a component name while importing it:

*Example string*:

```
import { Component } from 'components/components1
```

Regex used in the *Find* field:

```
import (\{(.*?)\}) from 'components/(componentgroup|componentgroup2|componentgroup3)
```

Pattern used in *Replace* field:

```
import $1 from 'ui/$2
```

This way I can select all occurrences, but can't get the expected results in the text.

Is there any other way than doing it manually?

I have also this regex, matches without brackets:

```
([^{}\s](?:[^{}]*[^{}\s])?)
```

Comment: Example: `import { Component } from 'components/components1`

Comment: What's wrong with what you wrote?

Comment: What do you mean by **can't use regex in the replace field.**? Where are you trying to do that?

Comment: It is clear what OP meant: **the result was not as expected**. I replaced the wrong wording with a clearer statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is fine, although you could write it with a word boundary at the end to make sure you match the components as whole words:

```js
import (\{(.*?)\}) from 'components/(componentgroup|componentgroup2|componentgroup3)\b
```

Next, your replacement pattern must be

```js
import $2 from 'ui/$3
```

where Group 2 comes first, then Group 3.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FfOHEG/2).

A bit more enhanced version:

```js
import\s+\{\s*(.*?)\s*\}\s+from\s+'components\/(componentgroup|componentgroup2|componentgroup3)\b
```

Replace with `import $1 from 'ui/$2`.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FfOHEG/4).

Due to `\s*` in `\{\s*(.*?)\s*\}` the package name will be trimmed from whitespace, and `\s+` will ensure the match will occur even if there are any kind and amount of whitespace between the words. Note Visual Studio Code regex is a bit specific and `\s` does not match line break chars unless there is `\r` or `\n` in the pattern, so, in this case, `\s` won't go across lines.

Comment: Or just remove the unnecessary first set of parentheses.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that is also an option.